# JQuery loading dialog effect

Tags: jquery, loading, effect

In the past I used YUI container for LOADING effect. Please see this link:

[**http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/container/panel-loading_clean.html**](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/container/panel-loading_clean.html)

But someone suggested to me to use jQuery. Can anybody let me know any link or code to create a loading effect in jquery like YUI has been providing?

Thanks, Ravi Bhartiya

Answer (score 2):

In order to get this functionality (easily), you will need to use [jQuery UI](http://ui.jquery.com).

You'll need to combine two of the widgets they have included in order to replicate that effect.

You'll need to put a [Progress Bar](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/) inside of a [Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).
To get the grayed out background effect, you'll need to enable the 'modal' attribute on the dialog.

Please see the jQuery UI documentation and demos for more info, as I'm not an expert with jQuery UI.

Answer (score 1):

This jQuery plugin might be what you are looking for http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#page?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this by using a combination of the jQuery UI [progressbar](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/#animated) and [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/). There may also be a jQuery plugin that you can use to achieve a similar effect.